# Preencher TextBox com valores do BindingSource Mover para proximo e Anterior, ultimo e primeiro

Tags: c#

Boa noite Galera,

estou com um problema em um projeto em c# onde eu preciso navegar em um bindingSource e ir preenchendo os campos do form com os valores referente a posição do bindingSource, eu ja tenho ele preenchido tudo certo problema ta quando eu vou para o próximo registro ele da erro no textBox dizendo que ja possui associação segue a mensagem "isso gera duas associações na coleção para ligar à mesma propriedade", abaixo segue o código

```
private void btnProximo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bindingSourcePais.Position + 1 < bindingSourcePais.Count)
        {
            try
            {
                proximo();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Util_Msg.erro(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }

    private void proximo()
    {
        bindingSourcePais.MoveNext();
        txtCodigo.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourcePais, "codigo");
        txtNome.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourcePais, "nome");

    }
```

Comment: Tire o código do `DataBindings.Add` de dentro do método que você executa toda vez que clicar no botão. Você só precisa associar o controle com o `bindingSource` uma única vez

Comment: Boa noite @RovannLinhalis, deu certo sua dica, eu não sabia desse detalhe muito obrigado